# How to change icon of a link after I created it?

Tags: vbscript, icons, shortcut

I made a script that will check for the existence of a link in user's desktop and if is not found, it will create it.
But then I want that link to have the icon changed and I don't know how to do it. I tried to use the `objDesktop` that I created, but it seems to be a different type of object, so I can't use `ParseName` or `GetLink` against it.

Code sample below:

```
Set wShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objFso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objDesktop = objFso.GetFolder(wShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"))

linkName = "\Notepad.lnk"
fullLinkPath = objDesktop & linkName

If (objFso.FileExists(fullLinkPath)) = False Then
    Set shortcut = wShell.CreateShortcut(fullLinkPath)
    shortcut.targetpath = "c:\Windows\notepad.exe"
    shortcut.Save
End If

'from here, I want that freshly created link to have its icon replaced with
'another ico file that will be provided.
```

I'd like to keep the code as simple and minimal as possible, so if my approach until now is not going to lead me to a consistent result, please give me a better code example.

Comment: The very same way you create a link, just remove the if and change the icon. `shortcut.IconLocation = "%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll,1"`

Answer (score 1):

Found the secret: by NOT using the if and directly calling .CreateShortcut.
"Creates a new shortcut, or opens an existing shortcut" - from "CreateShortcut Method" page on MSDN.

So, it seems there was no reason to check if shortcut exists, because it won't create a duplicate.